p-norm inequality of a matrix A and its absolute matrix |A|
I want to know if there exists a relationship between $\|A\|_p$ and $\| |A| \|_p$, where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $1\leq p \leq +\infty $. Such as $\|A\|_p=\||A|\|_p$ or $\|A\|_p \leq \||A|\|_p$?
Futher, if $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times q}$, how about $\|AB\|_p$, $\||AB|\|_p$ and $\| |A| |B|\|_p$?

By an absolute matrix, do you mean the same matrix but you have all negative numbers switched into positive ones?

Exactly as you say.
